# How to configure ImageMagick to work with Alfresco on CentOS7?

Tags: centos-7, imagemagick, alfresco

I installed Alfresco Community 6.1.2 on CentOS7. The section on ImageMagick just says to install it. I used the command:

```
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

Now, the alfresco.log shows this error:

> 2019-08-02 14:09:16,595 ERROR
>   [org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.magick.ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker]
>   [localhost-startStop-1] Remote ImageMagick is not available for
>   transformations. 07020018 Remote ImageMagick check failed to connect
>   or to read the response

This appears to be a misconfiguration in my alfresco-global.properties file. I have tried various alternates of the settings but this error stays.

```
#img.root=/ImageMagick
img.root=/usr/bin
#img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
#img.dyn=/usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.7.8/modules-Q16
img.dyn=/usr/lib64
img.exe=${img.root}/convert
#img.coders=${img.root}/modules/coders
#img.config=${img.root}/config
img.url=${img.root}/url
```

Why does the doc say to set img.root to /ImageMagick? Setting it to /usr/bin seems more logical as the convert command is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
I should not have added img.url settings. This was making Alfresco send an HTTP request for ImageMagick. Commenting this line fixed it.